Updating persisted zustand functions breaks app when deploying
Some background:
I'm building a new feature in a rather larger app. This feature should work across different pages so a state management solution is warranted. To handle such management, I've used zustand. I also want to persist the data across multiple browser tabs so I'm using the persist middleware.
The problem:
I made some changes to the zustand store I was using to manage the feature data (I broke it out from 1 -> 3 stores to modularize the logic a bit better). I then instrumented some  "best practices" one of which was to only export custom hooks https://tkdodo.eu/blog/working-with-zustand#only-export-custom-hooks. As a result of this change and since I was using persist (data is now stored in localStorage), previous functions that were exported from the store itself were no longer able to be found by the browser. In development, this meant just clearing localStorage, the problem was when I deployed the change. The user's browsers still have the old store information and therefore still had the error.
Question:
When using Zustand's persist middleware, how do you change stores such that those changes don't break deployments due to out dated localStorage?
Some things I've considered that just don't seem right:

An error boundary that resets localStorage if hit. Doesn't feel like the right fix for this very specific issue.
Don't use persist. Doesn't feel right because its a feature for a reason, we should be able to use it without bricking prod when we make a change to a persisted store.
Don't use Zustand to persist data. Similar feeling to above, I don't think a reasonable answer to this problem is "switch tools." There must be a way to use persisted data and make changes to it without this side effect of stale localStorage.
Asking the users to clear their localStorage. This option is just not good. Can't ask users to close their browsers or run localStoreage.clear themselves.

Here's some code that could help you debug:
interface StoreState {
  turns: any[];
}
interface StoreActions {
  actions: {
    setTurns: (newTurnsOrSetterFn: ReactStyleStateSetter<any[]>) => void;
    reset: () => void;
  };
}

const initialState: ChatSearchStoreState = {
  turns: [],
};

const useStore = create<
  StoreState & StoreActions
>()((set) => ({
  ...initialState,
  actions: {
    setTurns: (newTurnsOrSetterFn: ReactStyleStateSetter<Turn[]>) => {
      set(({ turns }) => {
        if (isArray(newTurnsOrSetterFn)) {
          const newTurns = newTurnsOrSetterFn;
          return { turns: newTurns };
        }
        const setterFn = newTurnsOrSetterFn;
        return { turns: setterFn(turns) };
      });
    },
    reset: () => set({ ...initialState }),
  },
}));

export const _useTurns = () => useChatSearchStore((state) => state.turns);
export const useChatSearchStoreActions = () =>
  useChatSearchStore((state) => state.actions);

Then use one of the functions in a component:
import {useTurns} from 'store';
function App() {
const turns = _useTurns();
return ( <div>hello there</div> )
}

When this is up, make a change to the store. Maybe just update _useTurns to useTurns. You should see that localStore is keeping around _useTurns and not setting useTurns as a function.
